# Interact with external commands via shell_exec

Tags: php, android, linux, centos

Recently I installed Android SDK on my CentOS server because of working with aapt, the aapt works great in command line via Putty SSH application.

Now, I want to run aapt commands through php `shell_exec` method.

My Android-SDK has been installed on `\ipl\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt`, but I can't interact with it through `shell_exec` method.

Code:

```
$out = shell_exec("/ipl/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt d badging t.apk 2>&1");
var_dump($out);
```

Result:

```
string(60) "sh: /ipl/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt: Permission denied "
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the file has enough permissions and if the user is able to execute the file.

Hope it helps

Comment: Could you please make more sense, how can I checking for the permissions ?!

Comment: If a file is executable for a user does not mean that the user is actually able to execute the file. 

The user also needs execution permission for the parent dirs.
Try to chmod o+x * -Rf to your parent folder "ipl"
chmod o+x will change recursively change all the children folders inside the "IPL"

Comment: So my code should be `$out = shell_exec("o+x * -Rf /ipl/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt d badging t.apk 2>&1");
var_dump($out);`, Right?

Comment: try accessing your box with ssh and then go to your folder ipl (cd location of ipl) and then run the chmod o+x -Rf

After setting chown try your command:
$out = shell_exec("/ipl/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt d badging t.apk 2>&1");

Comment: Still get Permission denied even after set this command => `chmod o+x -Rf /ipl/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt` with SSH.

Comment: try on you ssh console to chmod the parent folder (ipl) so that all the childrens inherit permissions
cd /ipl
chmod o+x ipl -Rf